# loop through JSON result with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, html, loops

i have the following JSON response, but i am not sure how to properly loop trough it and use.

```
{
  "ID": 1,
  "Name": "dept1",
  "Categories": [
    {
      "ID": 1,
      "Name": "catg1"
    },
    {
      "ID": 2,
      "Name": "catg2"
    }
  ]
}
```

following code alerts me the departmentID which is 1, then its name 'dept1', then this: `'[object Object],[object Object]'`

```
$.getJSON("mainPage2.aspx", function(result) {
   $.each(result, function(i, item) {
      alert(this);
   });
});
```

all i want to do is to create a div using department info, and create another div inside it which includes the information of categories that belong to that deparment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(var key in result) {
    var value = result[key];
    if(typeof value == 'object') {
        if(value instanceof Array) {
            // an array. loop through children
            for(var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
                var item = value[i];
            }
        } else {
            // complex object, not array. inner for loop on keys?
        }
    } else {
        // regular string/number etc. just print out value?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Well, its showing its getting the object alright, have you tried

```
    $.getJSON("mainPage2.aspx", function(result) {
   $.each(result, function(i, item) {
      alert(item.Name);
   });
});
```

Item being the object passed through from the each function it should pick this up and alert out 'dept1' or whatever the text is set

if you want to loop through the categories then do another loop i.e.

```
    $.getJSON("mainPage2.aspx", function(result) {
   $.each(result, function(i, item) {
      alert(item.Name);
        $.each(item.Categories, function(i, cat) {
           alert(cat.Name)
        }
   });
});
```

Comment: your solution makes sense, but returns "undefined".