# How to properly loop through JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Im trying to populate a combobox with data from database.

When I access mystream.php?theLocation=NewYork
I get this JSON response

**RESULT**

```
{"result":
[{"theID":"36"},{"theStream":"0817-05131"},{"theLabel":"hgjbn"},{"theLocation":"NewYork"},
{"theID":"37"},{"theStream":"0817-05131"},{"theLabel":"hgjbn"},{"theLocation":"NewYork"},
{"theID":"40"},{"theStream":"0817-31334"},{"theLabel":"dsfg ghjg"},{"theLocation":"NewYork"}]}
```

Applying the answer from this post
[loop through JSON result with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041497/loop-through-json-result-with-jquery)

**I came up with this JSON**

```
$.getJSON(
    'mystream.php',
    'theLocation=NewYork',
    function(result){
        $('#cmbNewYork').empty();
        $.each(result, function(i, item){
            $('#cmbNewYork').append('<option value=' +item.theStream+ '>'+item.theLabel+'</option>');
            alert(item.theStream);
        });
    }
);
```

My resulting combo box only contains undefined.

How to properly loop thru JSON response?

Thanks

**EDIT (ADDED)**

mystream.php

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Streams WHERE theLocation='$loc'";
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$result = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    array_push($result, 
            array('theID'=>$row['theID']),
            array('theStream'=>$row['theStream']),
            array('theLabel'=>$row['theLabel']),
            array('theLocation'=>$row['theLocation'])       
            );
}

echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
```

Comment: @CodeGodie: No, jQuery does that for you.

Comment: Youre right, i forgot he was using $.getJSON()

Comment: in that case you just need to say `$.each(result.result ` in your `each`. However as @T.J.Crowder mentioned, you need to fix your JSON structure.

Comment: @CodeGodie: Even `$.get`, `$.ajax`, and `$.post` will, provided the server returns the correct `Content-Type` or the code specifies `dataType: 'json'`.

Comment: right as long as that content-types/data-type is provided, which lots of time people forget.

Comment: all you need in your while loop is `array_push($result, $row);` Just make sure that your `SELECT` query gets the fields you need.

Comment: Or use [fetch_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) if available, and just use the array that is returned, ie `json_encode(mysqli_fetch_all($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC))`

Comment: @CodeGodie, thanks for that tip but I am filtering the result based on `theLocation`. Tried that and it return the whole table

Comment: @PatrickEvans, haven't tried fetch_all. will certainly save this for later reading. Thanks

Comment: @Wayne well it depends on your `SELECT` query. You need to specify which fields you want, so you would `SELECT theID, theStresm, theLabel, TheLocation FROM ...` This will speed up your code as well.

Comment: @CodeGodie I added the `SELECT` query for future readers benefits. Just in case you have something to enhance it. Thanks

Comment: awesome. glad your code is working well now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues:

The primary issue that your JSON format is very strange: It's an array of objects each of which has **one** name/value pair:

```
{"result": [
    {"theID":"36"},
    {"theStream":"0817-05131"},
    {"theLabel":"hgjbn"},
    {"theLocation":"NewYork"},
    {"theID":"37"},
    {"theStream":"0817-05131"},
    {"theLabel":"hgjbn"},
    {"theLocation":"NewYork"},
    {"theID":"40"},
    {"theStream":"0817-31334"},
    {"theLabel":"dsfg ghjg"},
    {"theLocation":"NewYork"}
]}
```

That's 12 separate objects.

You should have objects with *all* of those properties together:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "theID": "36",
            "theStream": "0817-05131",
            "theLabel": "hgjbn",
            "theLocation": "NewYork"
        },
        {
            "theID": "37",
            "theStream": "0817-05131",
            "theLabel": "hgjbn",
            "theLocation": "NewYork"
        },
        {
            "theID": "40",
            "theStream": "0817-31334",
            "theLabel": "dsfg ghjg",
            "theLocation": "NewYork"
        }
    ]
}
```

That's three objects, each with four properties.

Re your edit to the question, you can do that like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    array_push($result, 
            array(
                'theID'=>$row['theID'],
                'theStream'=>$row['theStream'],
                'theLabel'=>$row['theLabel'],
                'theLocation'=>$row['theLocation']
                )
            );
}
```

Note how that's creating **one** array per loop, rather than four.

The second issue is that you probably need `result.result`, rather than just `result`, on this line:

```
$.each(result.result, function(i, item){
// ----------^^^^^^^
```

...since `result` is your overall anonymous result, which has a single property, `result`, which has your array.

If you fix those, your loop should start working.

---

You don't *have* to do the `result.result` thing if you don't want to. Instead, you could have your JSON define an array instead of an object with a single property referring to the array:

```
[
    {
        "theID": "36",
        "theStream": "0817-05131",
        "theLabel": "hgjbn",
        "theLocation": "NewYork"
    },
    (and so on)
]
```

You haven't shown the PHP code creating `$result`, so I can't show you how to do that, but A) You don't need to, the `result.result` thing is fine, and B) If you want to, I'm sure you can figure it out.

Comment: I edit/add the query part in the php code to show how the data gets assigned to `$result`. might be helpful for future readers. Thanks again