# Linq Query To Recognize Rows As Columns

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a table which was the following:

```
ID   Pttributes           Pvalue

1   Name                  Jason  
2   Age                   14
3   Address               12 Test Road
```

A linq query has been produced which selects each individual value by their ID

```
from p in db.people
where p.ptribbutes.contain(string) || p.value.contains(string)                  
select p.tribbutes , p.value ,
```

Now this is where it gets tricky , when it is outputted towards JSON in MVC View , it outputted as separate rows in individual div elements (which has been incremented) where the code is written in javascript as

```
 item.ptribbutes + item.pvalue
```

Output value

```
Div 1
-------
Name - Jason

Div 2
--------
Age - 14

Div 3
--------- 
Address - 12 Test Road
```

How do I get it so one div can contain all these rows rather than being in separate div elements? (or possibly recognize the name , age and address as columns)?

Comment: This is called pivoting and LINQ is not the best tool for it.

Comment: Please show the Razor code that's producing that output.  And show the output that you want to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

1) Understand what is getting returned as JSON data. It is an array of objects.

2) How do you want it to display the JSON data in UI? I understand that as an single div for each array element. So what do you need to do is to loop thru the JSON data and either bind/emit the values in UI element inside (div) whichever way you prefer to do it. Take a look at the answer for the question at [loop through JSON result with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041497/loop-through-json-result-with-jquery)

Hope this helps. Happy Coding!